# The system call write(fd, buf, len) may return 0 when len > 0?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I saw code like this:

```
int my_write(int fd, char *buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t written = 0;

    while (len > 0) {
        if ((written = write(fd, buf, len)) < 0) {
                debug("write() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
                return -1;
        } else if (written == 0) {
            debug("write() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        len -= written;
        buf += written;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The man page on `Solaris` says this:

> Upon  successful  completion, write() returns the number of bytes actually written to the file associated with fildes. This number  is  never
>         greater than nbyte. Otherwise, -1 is returned, the file-pointer remains
>         unchanged, and errno is set to indicate the error.

So is it possible for `write(fd, buf, len /* > 0 */)` to return `0`? If yes, **when**?

#### UPDATE:

The `fd` is a *regular file* (not pipe, socket, ...) descriptor and it's in *blocking* mode.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where you saw this code?

Comment: What is a normal file descriptor? If it is an ordinary file, on what file system with which mount options?

Comment: Then, why not use `<stdio.h>` -or some libraries above it- for parsing a configuration file? And why would you *write* into a configuration file? Your question is really unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it may return zero. When the calling of that function will not write any thing then it will return the value zero.

From `man` page of `write`

> zero indicates nothing was written

---

```
if ( len > 0 )
```

This condition is for checking the given bytes are totally written or not.  This condition is for totally write the given bytes when no problem occurs in write function.

`len` is `1000` , first time write is write  write the bytes as `512`, but we need to write the 100 bytes to that file descriptor. So that we have to subtract the value of written bytes.

```
len -= written;
```

Now `len` have the value `488(1000-512)`. Now in next loop, write have to write the 488 bytes.

```
buf += written;
```

this is for we have written the 512 bytes. We have to write the remaining bytes so for that we have incrementing that pointer position to point out the remaining bytes.

```
( written == 0 )
```

It is for whether the above write function is write something or not. If it doesn't write anything then close for that.

---

As per your update, the above concept will more useful when we are writing into pipes,FIFO,and stream or network devices. In normal file descriptor it may not make any effect.

This will happen for normal file descriptor , when the file system runs out of space or we hit our quota limit. This condition is rare.  This concept is mainly for writing into other than normal file descriptors.

Comment: I guess what OP is asking is that since there is a `while(len > 0)` condition, whether the `if(written == 0)` condition is really necessary.

Comment: Then would you care to explain, under what circumstances, will it write nothing *without error* when `len` is greater than zero?

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S : Then when does `write` may return 0 when `len > 0`?

Answer (score 2):

From manual given [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)

> On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates
>   nothing was written). On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately.

So it says that write can return value > 0 if actually write something.

Comment: I guess what OP is asking is that since there is a `while(len > 0)` condition, whether the `if(written == 0)` condition is really necessary.

Comment: @ace That is not mentioned in question. Then how we will know that?

Comment: @niyasc: There's a `while (len > 0)` condition and I updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least on Linux, since the man page of [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) tells explicitly that

> On success, the number of bytes written is returned (*zero indicates nothing was written*).  On error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is set
>   appropriately.

BTW, I believe that in some weird cases you might get 0 as the number of bytes returned by `write` : e.g. a non-blocking pipe or socket - but that is generally the `EAGAIN` error -, or some weird socket (there are more than TCP or UDP sockets!), or perhaps some file in some NFS mounted filesystem with option `intr`, or perhaps when you have *exactly* reached some limit or some quota threshold; or some `write` to some weird device, etc...

So I would handle the rare case when `write` is giving 0 (and it is always better to special-case the `EAGAIN` & `EINTR` errors). I agree that `write` giving 0 is very uncommon, but I don't understand why you would avoid handling that case.

Comment: I guess what OP is asking is that since there is a `while(len > 0)` condition, whether the `if(written == 0)` condition is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, no.

From `man 2 write`:

```
RETURN VALUE
       On  success,  the  number  of bytes written is returned (zero indicates
       nothing was written).  On error, -1  is  returned,  and  errno  is  set
       appropriately.

       If  count  is  zero  and  fd refers to a regular file, then write() may
       return a failure status if one of the errors below is detected.  If  no
       errors  are  detected,  0  will  be  returned without causing any other
       effect.  If count is zero and fd refers to a file other than a  regular
       file, the results are not specified.
```

Due to the `while(len > 0)` condition, `write()` writes zero bytes *if and only if* it encounters an error, in which case it will return -1.

Comment: Not sure that `write` would never give 0 for a `len>0` ... See my answer

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I may be wrong. I am only providing my interpretation of the man pages.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The man page does not tell if it can return zero when count is not zero.